# Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension (Google Calendar API)

Tags: php, curl, ssh, google-calendar-api

I am new to using google calendar api and I need help with this issue. I worked on a php code, let us call this cal.php, and I opened it up on my website. On my website, I get this error, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension' in my directory.

To fix this issue, I downloaded curl and in my command line, when I type 'curl', I don't get an error message. However, the problem occurs when I ssh into my website and try typing in the word curl. I get this message curl: command not found. I tried putting my curl.exe and libssh2.dll in my website directory but that didn't work out. Any help is appreciated.

I have a windows 8 and I have php but I use iis 8.

Comment: you need php_curl.dll https://code.google.com/p/xampp-php-extensions/downloads/detail?name=php_curl.dll&can=2&q=

Comment: I already have php_curl.dll in my php folder. I copied the php_curl.dll and moved it into my directory but I still get the error message -sh curl:command not found.

Comment: php_curl should be in your ext directory and the line extension_dir = "ext" should be in your php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the php.ini file - make sure there is not a semi colon before the following line.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```